# не могу вывести массив большие своих соседей справа и слева

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(time(NULL));
    int const DOR = 20;
    double arr[DOR];
    int i, a = 0, b = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < DOR; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (double)rand() * (b - a) / RAND_MAX + a;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < DOR; i++)
    {
        printf("%6.2lf \r \n", arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < DOR; i++)
    {
        if ((arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) && (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]))
        {        
            printf("%6.2lf \r \n", arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

само задание :

> Сформировать с помощью датчика случайных чисел в диапазоне [0,10]
> массив из 20 элементов вещественного типа. Вывести его на экран.
> Вывести элементы массива, большие своих соседей справа и слева.

Answer (score 0):

вам надо найти элементы массива `arr[i]`, такие, что

```
(arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) && (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
```

вот и все

ну естественно ни первый ни последний элементы массива не могут быть выбраны, так что цикл будет от `1` до `DOR - 1`

```
for (int i = 1; i < DOR - 1; i++)
{
    if ((arr[i] > arr[i-1]) && (arr[i] > arr[i+1]))
    {
         printf("%6.2lf \r \n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: так. я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: @William Turner, допустим массив `[1, 3, 4, 2, -1, -8, -5, -6]` - у числе `3`, '-5' соседи справа и слева меньше их - вот вам это и надо найти

Comment: попытался сделать, но не получается. без изменений выводит

Comment: код в своем вопросе приведите - посмотрю, что не так

Comment: изменил. пытался еще сделать через if

Comment: @William Turner, не увидел в формуле if :) и я же написал - 1 и последний элемент не рассматриваем иначе p[i-1] уходит за границу!!! и тоже самое с последним элементом вправо

Comment: та що так сложно-то XD. я попробовал через if( изменил вопрос)

Comment: @William Turner, а теперь вы if вне цикла записали

Comment: хм.. ничего не меняется. скорее я что-то не знаю еще по этой теме

Comment: @William Turner, в конце ответа добавил код

Comment: спасибо за помощь.